# TCP client read and write socket in android service

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, android-service

I have about 9 activities in my android project. I need to continuously be communicating to the server using TCP socket (read and write). Since every activity that is opened needs to communicate to the server, I was planning to write the TCP communication code in a service and let the activity bind to it. Since I need to use two threads, one to continuously read the incoming data from the server and another to send data to the server using the same socket, I was not sure how to go about it.

I was thinking of using a timer to schedule to read the socket every 100 ms. I was planning to use a Messenger for the communication between the activity and the service. But I am not sure if this is the right way to go. Any help is appreciated. It would be very helpful if you could direct me to any available example codes or suggest better ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a timer. Just read continuously. It will block while there is no data.